# VBScript in VB.NET, Error messages

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

i want to write this VBScript as VB.NET. But it doesnt work....
Here my VBScript:

```
'VBScript
Dim strServer
strServer = "LP-BK"
Set objConnection = GetObject("WinNT://" & strServer & "/LanmanServer")
Set colSessions  = objConnection.Sessions

on error resume next
For Each objSession in colSessions
    Msgbox("objSession Computer is: " & objSession.Computer)
    Msgbox("objSession User is: " & objSession.User)
Next 

Set objConnection = nothing
Set ColResources = nothing
Set colSessions  = nothing
```

Here is my VB.Net Code, which doesnt work.

```
'Imports ActiveDs
'and add a reference on the com tab to Active DS Type Library 

Private Sub bSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles bSave.Click


    Dim fso As IADsFileServiceOperations


    On Error GoTo Cleanup
    fso = GetObject("WinNT://LP-BK/LanmanServer") ' There is a error: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'ActiveDs.IADsFileServiceOperations'.

    For Each session In fso.Sessions
        MsgBox(session.Computer) ' Error: Option Strict On disallows late binding.
    Next

    Cleanup:
            If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
                MsgBox("An error has occurred. " & Err.Number)
            End If
            fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

I hope you can help mee....
Many thanks in advance
greetings

Edit: Someone any idea?

Comment: Have you attempted to explicitly cast your `GetObject` result?

Comment: HI george, thank you for ur answer. What does you exactly mean with "cast your getobject result"?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you going you could just add `Option Strict Off` at the top of your class. That way it would work more like VBScript.

In the longer term though you will want to re-write this so that is compiles with Option Strict On

If you want someone to translate VBScript code into VB.NET code for you then you have come to the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, i dont wnat to write Option Strict Off... its okay that is option strict on.. but the problem is more, how is the code, if its options strict on?

Comment: Yes, but that don't resolve my problem/question. Otherwise dont understand you correctly.